# Validate file extension for Upload Multiple File on Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Invalid File. Please upload a File with Extension .JPEG , .JPG, .PNG" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <div style="width:50%; float:left; height:400px; overflow:auto;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Image Name" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Value" HeaderText="Image" ControlStyle-Height="100" ControlStyle-Width="100" />
            </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

C# :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime curr = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(curr, "India Standard Time");

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string FileExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    if (FileExtention == ".jpg")
                    {
                        string time1 = INDIAN_ZONE.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmss");
                        string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("./upload/" + TextBox1.Text));
                        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }

                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                        fileName = time1 + fileName;
                        string path = "./upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/";
                        hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path) + fileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new ListItem(fileName1, "~/upload/" + TextBox1.Text + "/" + fileName1));
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string time1 = INDIAN_ZONE.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmss");
            string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("./upload/" + TextBox1.Text));
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using ASP.Net and C#.
When i click on Upload Button, i want to check every file on FileUpload if File Extension are Valid(JPEG, JPG, PNG) then file save on folder if any file are not Valid then show that file name on Label and do nothing.
How to achieve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will not be a good way to show error on each file upload as files in loop are being uploaded so only last file with any other extension will be shown on label what you can do is add file names in a string and at end of all files have been uploaded show the label that following files have not been  uploaded or you can create labels at runtime whenever a file with other extension is uploaded.

```
string filenames="";
if(extension="JPG")
uploadfile()
else
filenames+=hpf.FileName+",";

filenames.TrimEnd(",");
label.Text="Following files have not been uploaded "+filenames;
```

Method2

```
 if(extension="JPG")
 uploadfile()
 else
 Label lb=new Label();
 lbl.Text=hpf.FileName+" not uploaded please upload with JPG";
 //Add lbl to your div or any other control.
```